# xdg-open: no method available for opening 'http://localhost:8080'

Tags: linux, extjs, webpack

I have Ext React project. I try to run command:

```
npm start
```

Everything builds OK, but in the end I get an error:

```
webpack: Compiled successfully.
/home/user/project/node_modules/open-browser-webpack-plugin/index.js:46
        if (err) throw err;
                 ^

Error: Command failed: /home/user/project/node_modules/open/vendor/xdg-open "http://localhost:8080"
xdg-open: no method available for opening 'http://localhost:8080'

    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:198:12)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:920:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:230:5)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! project@1.0.0 start: `webpack-dev-server --progress --colors`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the project@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/user/.npm/_logs/2017-10-28T11_56_32_483Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved this problem, by editing webpack config file. There I turned off opening browser after build finishes, by commenting "New OpenBrowserPlugin" like below:

```
plugins.push(new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    template: 'index.html',
    hash: true
})/*, new OpenBrowserPlugin({ 
    url: `http://localhost:${port}`
})*/);
```